# "Pandorable" way to return index in dataframe slicing

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

Is there a pandorable way to get only the index in dataframe slicing? 
In other words, is there a better way to write the following code:

df.loc[df['A'] >5].index

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Yes, better is filter only index values, not all DataFrame and then select index:

```
#filter index
df.index[df['A'] >5]

#filter DataFrame
df[df['A'] >5].index
```

Difference is in performance too:

```
np.random.seed(1245)
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':np.random.randint(10, size=1000)})
print (df)

In [40]: %timeit df.index[df['A'] >5]
208 µs ± 11.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [41]: %timeit df[df['A'] >5].index
428 µs ± 6.42 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [42]: %timeit df.loc[df['A'] >5].index
466 µs ± 40.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

---

If performance is important use `numpy` - convert values of index and column by [`values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.values.html) to numpy array:

```
In [43]: %timeit df.index.values[df['A'] >5]
157 µs ± 8.71 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)

In [44]: %timeit df.index.values[df['A'].values >5]
8.91 µs ± 196 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```