# Pandas Dataframe - select columns with a specific value in a specific row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to select columns with a specific value (say 1) in a specific row (say first row) for Pandas Dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), for performance is better filtering `index` not `DataFrame` and then select index (see [performance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52532000/2901002)):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
        'A':list('abcdef'),
         'B':[4,5,4,5,5,4],
         'C':[7,8,9,4,2,3],
         'D':[1,3,5,7,1,0],
         'E':[5,3,6,9,2,4],
         'F':list('aaabbb')
})

print (df)
   A  B  C  D  E  F
0  a  4  7  1  5  a
1  b  5  8  3  3  a
2  c  4  9  5  6  a
3  d  5  4  7  9  b
4  e  5  2  1  2  b
5  f  4  3  0  4  b

s = df.iloc[0]        
a = s.index[s == 1]
print (a)
Index(['D'], dtype='object')

a = s.index.values[(s == 1)]
print (a)
['D']
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use this

```
df['a'][df['a']==0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) to extract a row as a series, then apply your condition:

```
row = df.iloc[0]           # extract first row as series
res = row[res == 1].index  # filter for values equal to 1 and get columns via index
```