# How to select columns with a specific value iterating all rows in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe

I found this  [Pandas Dataframe - select columns with a specific value in a specific row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53206536/pandas-dataframe-select-columns-with-a-specific-value-in-a-specific-row)
But I couldn't figure out how to do this in iteration from user input.

```
no_to_search = input()
with open('jen.csv', 'rt') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        if no_to_search==row
        df=pd.read_csv('jen.csv')
        for col in df.columns:
            if (df[col] == 1).any():
                print(col)
```

[refer image via this link [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aJAHx.png)]

I want to retrieve column names with value 1 for the input row matching.

Comment: Do you have a full list of the column names you want to retrieve? If yes: 
import pandas as pd 
df = pd.read_csv(filename, usecols=list_of_col_names)

Comment: I'm sorry, I think I misread you question. Could you give an example of what you want, e.g. an example of data, and what you would like to extract?

Comment: @ABotros could you follow up

Comment: I've updated post with sample image of data and I need to retrieve column names with value 1 corresponding for the input number

Comment: Do you want to iterate through all the rows and get all the column names that has 1 in it or look for all the columns that has the value in the entire data frame?

Comment: Former one ...I want to iterate through all the rows and get those column names that has 1 for the corresponding input number (no)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I think I have finally fully understood your problem.
If I have understood your question correctly,

- you want to retrieve the columns where the value of a certain row matches your condition (value = 1) 
  Example code:

```
>> import pandas as pd
>> df = pd.DataFrame([[1,0,1],[0,1,0],[1,1,0]], columns=["car_db","bike_db","van_db"], index=["7602102000", "7602201132", "7622315645"])
>> df
            car_db  bike_db van_db
7602102000  1       0       1
7602201132  0       1       0
7622315645  1       1       0

>> df.to_csv("tmp.csv")
```

The example data is in a cvs file called "tmp.csv" and is exactly like your example. 
You want the name of the columns, where the phone number is 7602102000 and the value is 1:

```
>> df = pd.read_csv("tmp.csv", index_col=0)
>> no = 7602102000  # phone number inputed by your users
>> col_names = df.columns[(df.loc[df.index == no].values==1)[0]]
>> col_names
Index(['car_db', 'van_db'], dtype='object')
>> df[col_names]
            car_db  van_db
7602102000  1       1
7602201132  0       0
7622315645  1       0
```

This will print you all columns where the condition is met.

Comment: There are four columns namely ('phone no','db1','db2','db3') ...i want to let user to input 'phone no' as external input and i want to match that with 'phone no' in dataframe and return the column names with 1 as value for that specific record....

Comment: I'm getting the index of the matching outputs ..how to get the values of columns from the matching indexes?

Comment: ah, ok, so you want the whole columns where the condition is met? Just call your dataframe with df[col_names]. This will return all columns (with values) where the condition is met.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a much more efficient way of doing this. Changed the code to suit your question. Add another condition to the lambda.

`df.apply(lambda x: print(x.index[(x['phone no'] == number) & (x.isin([1])].values), axis = 1)`

If you want to add a column to your data frame:

`df['cols'] = df.apply(lambda x: print(x.index[(x['phone no'] == number) & (x.isin([1])].values), axis = 1)`

I am sure there's a much efficient way of doing this. This should work. Let me know if it doesn't.

`for i in range(len(df)):
    if df.columns[(df == 1).iloc[i]].notna():
        print(df.columns[(df == 1).iloc[i]].values)`

Comment: Thanks..But this displays the column names for the entire rows for the matching condition..How could i only display the column names for specific row no that i input ?

Comment: `df.columns[(df == 1).iloc[row_number]].values`

Comment: User input i mean....there are four columns namely ('phone no','db1','db2','db3') ...i want to let user to input 'phone no' as external input and i want to match that with 'phone no' in dataframe and return the column names with 1 as value....Hope you get it now..

Comment: `df.apply(lambda x: print(x.index[(x['phone no'] == number) & (x.isin([1]))].values), axis = 1)`

Comment: It prints empty arrays for other rows as well as printing required output for that row..can't i get the required array only?